# Unable to connect Oracle from visual studio 2010 in windows 7 64 bit

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0, oracle10g

I have installed Oracle 10g in my windows 7 , 64 bit, here I am able to connect with `sql plus` successfully using:

**user name : test, password : test, and host string : test**

but when I am trying to connect in my visual studio 2010 using:

**connection string : Data Source=test;user id=test;password:test;**

but it is not able to connect, it is giving error :

**ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified.**

Even I tried using:

**Data Source:(Host, port,...)(coppied from transname.ora file)**

in this case I am getting error :

**ORA-06413: Connection not open.**

I have wasted 3-4 days but I am not able to connect, so friend could you please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these formats (from [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/)):

```
SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
uid=myUsername;pwd=myPassword;
```

or

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```